# Cargar función de input al cargar página

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero que al cargar la pagina me aparezca el numero formateado o con separadores de miles para dos `input,` que son: `VALOR` y `KILOMETRAJE.` tengo la misma función pero en un evento `onkeyup`. intente poner el código de la siguiente forma para que formatee por lo menos en un el `input VALOR` sin éxito alguno.

**SCRIPT**

```
window.onload = format(VALOR);

function format(VALOR){
    var num = VALOR.value.replace(/\./g,'');
    if(!isNaN(num)){
        num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
        num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
        VALOR.value = num;
    }
    else
    { 
        alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
        VALOR.value = VALOR.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
    } 
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="VALOR" id="VALOR" value="<?php echo $fila['VALOR']; ?>" /> 
<input type="text" name="VALOR" id="VALOR" value="<?php echo $fila['VALOR']; ?>" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pasa es que debe mandarle la referencia al campo a el cual quiere formatear, ya sea por su Id u otro atributo, además de que le está dando el mismo id a dos input y está llamando mal la función window.onload.
Podría ser la solución así:

```js
window.onload = function() {
  format(document.getElementById("VALOR1"));
  format(document.getElementById("VALOR2"));
}

function format(VALOR) {
  var num = VALOR.value.replace(/\./g, '');
  if (!isNaN(num)) {
    num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g, '$1.');
    num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/, '');
    VALOR.value = num;
  } else {
    alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
    VALOR.value = VALOR.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g, '');
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="VALOR1" id="VALOR1" value="1000" />
<input type="text" name="VALOR2" id="VALOR2" value="20000000" />
```

Answer (score 4):

Lo que pasa es que estas pasando el la función `format` al evento  `onload` directamente y en ningún caso estas incluyendo el `input` que requieres formatear.

Para este caso te conviene hacer lo siguiente:

```js
window.onload = function () {
  var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('.valor');
  inputs.forEach(function (input) {
      format(input);
  }); 
}

function format(VALOR){
    var num = VALOR.value.replace(/\./g,'');
    if(!isNaN(num)){
        num = num.toString().split('').reverse().join('').replace(/(?=\d*\.?)(\d{3})/g,'$1.');
        num = num.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/^[\.]/,'');
        VALOR.value = num;
    }
    else
    { 
        alert('Solo se permiten numeros');
        VALOR.value = VALOR.value.replace(/[^\d\.]*/g,'');
    } 
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="VALOR" class="valor" id="VALOR1" value="1000" />
  <input type="text" name="VALOR" class="valor" id="VALOR2" value="11000" />
```

donde el evento `window.onload` recibe una función que en su interior obtiene todos los inputs (Ojo con los IDs, estos no pueden repetirse dentro de un mismo documento), luego iteras sobre los mismos pasandole como parámetro el input.